# Jasper Report Error retrieving field value from bean al generar Informe con fichero JSON

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

me vuelvo a conectar con vds. ya que las ultimas veces me habeis ayudado y estoy con este problema desde hace ya un tiempo y de solucionarlo depende mi puesto de trabajo pues estoy en practicas y tengo que solucionarlo.

mi JSON:

```js
[
  {
    "fecha": "03/07/2018 08:16:58",
    "velocidad_up": "30",
    "velocidad_dw": "30",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443596ACB9B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443596ACB9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "03/07/2018 08:23:13",
    "velocidad_up": "30",
    "velocidad_dw": "30",
    "ppoe_usuario": "4857544321F99C9B",
    "ppoe_password": "4857544321F99C9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "04/07/2018 18:58:02",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC26FB9B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC26FB9B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "05/07/2018 08:33:00",
    "velocidad_up": "10",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC23E79B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC23E79B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "06/07/2018 18:50:29",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "20",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443A351D79B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443A351D79B",
    "c": "0"
  },
  {
    "fecha": "06/07/2018 18:53:13",
    "velocidad_up": "5",
    "velocidad_dw": "25",
    "ppoe_usuario": "48575443DC26A59B",
    "ppoe_password": "48575443DC26A59B",
    "c": "0"
  }
]
```

El caso es que al intentar generar un informe en JASPER REPORT con columnas dynamicas a partir de un fichero JSON, al llegar a la linea donde se genera Jasper print aparece el siguiente error:

```js
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fecha.
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:193)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:158)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1489)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1390)
```

este error se produce en la linea :

```js
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, dataSource);
```

Pero en  realidad se ve que NETBEANS da un aviso en las lineas :

```js
 public static JRDataSource getDatasource(List<AbstractColumn> columns) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("C:/tools/2datos-prue.json"), JsonElement.class);
         datosJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<JsonElement>>(){}.getType());
          List data = new ArrayList();
         data.addAll(datosJson);
         List data3 = new ArrayList();
        data3 =  SortUtils.sortCollection(data, columns);
                     
       return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data3, false);
```

En concreto en la linea :

```js
 data3 =  SortUtils.sortCollection(data, columns);
```

dando los siguientes errores :

```js
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'fecha'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_up'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_dw'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ppoe_usuario'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'ppoe_password'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'c'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'fecha'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare
ADVERTENCIA: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'velocidad_up'
ago 20, 2019 10:15:55 AM ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.MultiPropertyComparator compare ....
```

El error se repite por cada una de las columnas donde estan los datos.

Estoy  muy agobiado por este problema... me gustaria me ayudaran .....

Gracias de todas formas a todos, Espero vuestras ideas ojala encuentre la solucion....

Pd:

Fichero solicitado DatosJson

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te fijaste que en esta linea de código: datosJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<JsonElement>>(){}.getType()); la variable datosJson contenga los datos que quieres mostrar en el reporte?

Comment: si, lo unico es que ocurre es que viendo el mismo fichero con otras fuentes de datos  la estructura cambia un poco, la voy a poner,  pero al mirarla a fondo se ven tods los campos correctamente o eso me parece a mi ....

Comment: ahi lo tienes la estructura se repite por cada  uno de los registros.. as diferencias es que ponen un elemento "members" y todo lo demas va dentro .y los tipos de elementos estan marcados como "LinkedTreeMap$node", que creo es por el tipo de elemento que se obtiene ,,,,,